# Western Australia: 2 weeks in the Wort - is this too long in summer time?

Tags: wort

Usually in summer in WA I can bottle my beers within one week of placing the ingredients in the wort (plastic fermenting bucket with airlock).  This is due to the average temperature being 25-30 degrees celcius (day and night).

Recently I placed a Coopers Pale Ale in the wort with cultivated yeast (I use 1/3 bottle bought coopers pale ale and add diluted sugar in water and leave for 1 week prior to adding to watt).  I have been busy working away from home and it is still in the wort after two and a half weeks.  It stopped bubbling one week ago.

Is it still ok to bottle?

Comment: Sean - this is a possible duplicate of "Too Long in Primary Fermentation?" http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/785/too-long-in-primary-fermentation  That should answer your question.  Also, for future reference, calling your primary fermentor "the wort" may be confusing to some.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's almost certainly safe, barring funky odors, colors, etc. If everything was properly sterilized, the yeast should have consumed the fermentables.
2. That's a pretty temperature of ambient air - the wort temperature is apt to be higher, which isn't great for making good beer
3. I'm somewhat surprised that there's live yeast in a bottle of Coopers - must be if you were able to cultivate it. It'll be interesting to see what comes out.

So bottle, and drink. It'll be beer, of some sort. If you're really worried, taste-test before bottling.